# Cannot connect to Compute Engine instance via SSH in linux

Tags: linux, ssh, google-compute-engine, gcloud

This question have answer before but that's for windows. But Now i am in linux.

I messed up lot. Please help me to solve this issue.

I created ssh pair using `ssh-keygen` command then i copied and pasted `id_rsa.pub` into `vminstace` `SSH Keys` and then saved. I issued below command but that's not going

```
gcloud compute --project "project001" ssh --zone "europe-west1-b" "instance-3"
```

Above command creates two file `google_compute_engine` and `google_compute_engine.pub` Then error is :

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: Try renaming id_rsa.pub to google_compute_engine.pub and see if this will work

Answer (score 3):

You have added your SSH public key  (id_rsa.pub) to the instance metadata and the gcloud command has added the other public key (google_compute_engine.pub) to the project metadata.

However, the instance metadata overrides the project metadata so you were trying to SSH using a non-authorized key.

Therefore, I propose four different solutions for your case:

1- Use the standard SSH client:

```
ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS
```

2- Add the google_compute_engine.pub key to the instance metadata and SSH into the instance using the gcloud command.

3- Remove the SSH keys from the instance metadata and SSH into the instance running the gcloud command.

4- [SSH from the browser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser).

I hope this helps.

Comment: This helped me too. Also you can place the settings from solution 1 into the `~/.ssh/config` so that you can simply do `ssh myinstance` everytime, as suggested [here](http://blog.javabien.net/2014/03/13/connect-to-a-compute-engine-directly-with-ssh/)

Answer (score 1):

From web login into SSH terminal , edit sshd_config make password athentication to yes save file and restart SSH once then login from your pc using any SSH client ...

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of background: Google Compute Engine maintains a list of public keys in each project's metadata.  You can see these by going to https://console.developers.google.com and navigating to

```
Compute > Compute Engine > Metadata > SSH KEYS.
```

Additionally GCE attempts to make sure that each of your VM's shows these keys in its  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

For it's part gcloud will attempt to create and register a new key when you invoke `gcloud ssh` and the key pair google_compute_engine, google_compute_engine.pub doesn't exist.

It appears that by hand editing your authorized_keys file this process got out of sync.

To get back into a know good state, go to https://console.developers.google.com, navigate to

```
  Compute > Compute Engine > VM instances
```

then click on SSH under the Connect column by your instance.  This will launch SSH as a browser pluggin and have the side effect of resyncing your authorized_keys file.  After that you should be able to ssh into your instance as usual using `gcloud compute ssh`.

In general it's okay, btw, to use other ssh keys with GCE VMs, but you should do this by adding keys to project metadata, and letting GCE handle propagation for you.